# getting a 6kb avi file while trying to record video with opencv and tkinter

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I have a multi frame/pages Tkinter application and in one page/frame I have a camera frame which starts the camera and stars capturing when I navigate to that page now I want to record that video but when I tried to record it I am getting a 6kb ```avi`` file which is not working at all and seems corrupted.

my code

```
class FrontCameraPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="FRONT CAMERA", font=MediumFont, bg="white").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.cameraFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg=gray)
        self.cameraFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=(10, 0))


#creating buttons and frames --
        self.end= tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="STOP", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, fg="White")
        self.end.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=10, pady=(0, 5))
        self.end['command'] = self.stop_capture

        self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Cancel", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, fg="white")
        self.cancelButton.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=10)
        self.cancelButton['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(someOtherPage)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # setup callbacks for switching in and out events starts and stops when I change frames
        self.bind('<<SwitchIn>>', self.start_capture)
        self.bind('<<SwitchOut>>', self.stop_capture)

        self.capture = None  # task id for the capture loop
        width, height = 200, 200
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)


        self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', self.fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))        
        self.lmain = tk.Label(self.cameraFrame)
        self.lmain.pack()

    def start_capture(self, event=None):
        if self.capture is None:
            self.show_frame()
            print('capture started')


    def stop_capture(self, event=None):
        if self.capture:
            self.after_cancel(self.capture)
            self.out.release()
            self.capture = None
            print('capture stopped')


    def show_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            #----------------------------------------------------------------
            self.out.write(cv2image)
            #----------------------------------------------------------------
            self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            self.lmain.configure(image=self.imgtk)
        self.capture = self.after(10, self.show_frame)
```

Comment: If you print out the frame size using `print(frame.shape)` inside `show_frame()`, you will find that the actual frame size is not 200x200.  So the output frame size when creating the video writer does not match with the actual frame size. You need to get the actual frame size using `self.cap.get(...)` after calling `self.cap.set(...)`.

Comment: If you are working in Windows: Make sure your application has access to the opencv_ffmprg dll,which is necessary for successful video writing.

Comment: @Micka yes i am on windows and looked into how to set  opencv_ffmprg but I am not able to find openCv folder on "C" drive

Comment: Sorry, had a typo. Search for opencv_ffmp* it should be st the same location as the rest of all opencv dll binaries.

Comment: @Micka i cant find them

Comment: @Micka i downloaded open cv using pip install

Comment: Can you find any other opencv_*.dll file? Are you using anaconda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the actual frame size returned by `self.cap.read()` does not match the size when creating the video writer.

You need to get the actual frame size using `self.cap.get(...)` after calling `self.cap.set(...)`:

```py
class FrontCameraPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        ... 

        width, height = 200, 200
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)

        # get the final frame size
        width = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
        height = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

        self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', self.fourcc, 20.0, (width, height))
        ...
```

Comment: I am on windows and looked into how to set opencv_ffmprg but I am not able to find openCv folder on "C" drive I downloaded opencv using pip is that a problem or i have to download it using there  exe installer

Comment: @stark I think required DLL should be included when installing `opencv-python` module.  Did you get any error on not finding any DLL when you execute the script?  Did you try my suggestion in my answer?

Comment: yes i tried this code which you have sent but its not working I think the problem may be in opencv_ffmpg

Comment: Just saying *"Its not working"* does not let us to help.  You need to describe what is not working and post the full traceback of any error you got.

Comment: And while running the application I am not getting any error only these warning ```[ WARN:1] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback```

Comment: Try `self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)`.

Comment: not working means the error what i was getting before i.e a 6 KB avi file which is corrupted

Comment: this ```self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)``` is giving this ```[ERROR:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (299) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(DSHOW): raised unknown C++ exception!


[ERROR:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (597) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of ..........```

Comment: Then I cannot help any more as the code works for me in my Windows 7 running Python 3.8.12 and opencv-python 4.5.4.60.

Comment: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/how-to-record-video-in-opencv-python this is working for me so the problem is not in opencv any idea?

Comment: If it works for you, just use it in your code.  I don't have any idea on that.

Comment: ok it was not for tkinter that's why I asked

Comment: Last suggestion: change `width, height = 200, 200` to `width, height = 640, 480`  and `self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')` to `self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')` based on the code in the link.  You need to understand what the code does and apply the logic to your code.

Comment: thanks but I fixed it the problem was in show frame insted of passing cv2image we have to pass frame in out

Comment: can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/q/70299621/16875055 thanks