# how to upload video to AWS while capturing videos using openCV python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tkinter

I have a Tkinter multiFrame/pages application In one of the frames i have camera related work i.e when I go on the page the camera automatically start and start capturing 20 sec video recording with openCV that means when video gets 20 second long it saves video locally and then starts recording new video of 20 second now i want those videos to upload on aws when a video gets recorded and got saved locally how can i achieve that whenever a video gets record i want that video should upload to aws automatically and get deleted from local computer and than this process should again start when new 20 second video is recorded.

my code

```
class FrontCameraPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller


        self.cameraFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg=gray)
        self.cameraFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.buttonFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        self.buttonFrame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=(10, 0))

        self.stop= tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="END TRIP", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, fg="White")
        self.stop.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=10, pady=(0, 5))
        self.stop['command'] = self.stop_capture

        self.cancelButton = tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Cancel", font=small_Font, bg=dark_blue, fg="white")
        self.cancelButton.grid(row=3, column=0, ipadx=10)
        self.cancelButton['command'] = lambda: controller.show_frame(go_to_some_page)

        # setup callbacks for switching in and out events
        self.bind('<<SwitchIn>>', self.start_capture)
        self.bind('<<SwitchOut>>', self.stop_capture)

        self.lmain = tk.Label(self.cameraFrame)
        self.lmain.pack()
        self.capture = None

    def start_capture(self, event=None):
        if self.capture is None:
            #-----------------------------------
            width, height = 200, 200
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
            self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
            # used instance variables for width and height
            self.width = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
            self.height = int(self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
            # initialize file rotation and frame counters
            self.timer = 1    # file rotation counter
            self.frames = 0   # frame counter
            self.fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
            self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(
                f'{self.timer}.avi', self.fourcc, 25, (self.width, self.height))
            #-----------------------------------
            self.show_frame()
            print('capture started')

    def stop_capture(self, event=None):
        if self.capture:
            self.after_cancel(self.capture)
            #-----------------------------------
            self.cap.release()
            self.out.release()
            #------------------------------
            self.capture = None
            print('capture stopped')


    def show_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        if ret:
            self.out.write(frame)
            self.frames += 1   
            if self.frames >= 500:    
                self.out.release()    
                self.timer += 1       
                self.out.open(f'{self.timer}.avi', self.fourcc, 25, (self.width, self.height))
                self.frames = 0       
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            self.lmain.configure(image=self.imgtk)
        self.capture = self.after(10, self.show_frame)
```

Comment: start in `thread` function which will do it.

Comment: the opencv and tkinter parts of your question are beside the point. you are asking **how to upload a file**. focus on that. at most you'll need threads so the GUI isn't blocked by the upload.

Comment: how can i do threading in this.